# I don't see the changes from Server A in server B

Tags: mysql, replication

SERVER A
config file:

```
server-id=1
log-bin="mysql-bin"
binlog-do-db=replicatietest
replicate-do-db=replicatietest
relay-log="mysql-relay-log"
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 1
```

command:

```
CREATE USER 'replicator'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Slave123';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replicator'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Slave123';
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
       --> mysql-bin.000003 397 replicatietest
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = 'Server A IP Address', MASTER_USER = 'replicator', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'Slave123', MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'mysql-bin.000003', MASTER_LOG_POS = 397; 
START SLAVE;
      --> OK
```

Server B
config file:

```
server-id=2
log-bin="mysql-bin"
binlog-do-db=replicatietest
replicate-do-db=replicatietest
relay-log="mysql-relay-log"
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 2
```

commands

```
CREATE USER 'replicator'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Slave123';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replicator'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'Slave123';
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
   --> mysql-bin.000001 154 replicatietest
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = 'Server B IP Address', MASTER_USER = 'replicator', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'Slave123', MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'mysql-bin.000001', MASTER_LOG_POS = 154; 
START SLAVE;
    --> OK
```

I can ping the ip adresses. But when I change something in Server A in the replicatietest, I don't see anything in server B.

Server A and B have both the scheme replicatietest.

Comment: `USE replicatietest;`.  Then try your query. Partial replication is much more difficult to do correctly than full replication, and almost always a bad idea.

Comment: then try wich query? And what is the difference about the full and partial? I use partial because I only want to replicate the replicatietest database? Is that right?

Comment: I think the values of log-bin and relay-log aren't right. Do you know what should be the values?

Comment: You should try executing a query while the desired database is your session's *current* database.  Depending on some other factors, MySQL doesn't magically know that you want the statement replicated, otherwise.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot!

Comment: See [How Servers Evaluate Replication Filtering Rules](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-rules.html).  I assume, since you say this helps, that you were not aware of all of the implications of partial replication.